# Adding APIs to WSO2 store times out

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to use the a curl command to add a API to the publisher site. I am using the sample code listed in the guide, but I am getting a timeout error code right away.

Here is the guide I am using: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publisher+APIs

I am using the Add API call, with the youtube sample. Is there a bug in the example?

Comment: Can you update the question with the error log?

Comment: Thats another problem. There are no errors in any of the logs. The only thing I get back is from the curl command: {"error" : true, "message" : "timeout"} And that returns right away.

Comment: Can you post the curl command you are sending?

Comment: It is exactly the same as the example, just going to my host:  http://pastebin.com/xRwFeQb4

Comment: @brianlee : Have you execute `Login` API first?

Comment: Yes the login API worked correctly. I can see that in the log files.

Comment: Okay I feel dumb now. I did log in, but it was to the wrong url. Once I corrected it I was able to add the test API correctly. Sorry to bother everyone.